# Syntax to retrieve the specific object (Ex: server, group etc) value in below json data in azure data factory

Tags: dataflow, azure-data-factory

I have a row and in that we have a column called data. The below json is present in the data column. So I want to retrieve single object from json like name present inside the survey node.

{"build":{"version":"8.3.4.23"},"survey":{"database":"abc","id":952,"name":"ravi","server":"ABCD0045","group":"JKLMN"}}

I will provide survey and name as the input parameters and my output has to be ravi. is there any syntax to get this in azure data factory dataflow activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-parse) transformation in Data Flow to parse your data column.

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Then you can use this expression `json.survey.name` to get the value `ravi`.